# How to use MINIFS in conditional formatting referencing another sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am trying to format a cell in one sheet based on the minimum value corresponding with certain criteria in a range of cells in another sheet.

In the sheet pictured here [Sheet "Week 1"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sGj8.png) titled "Week 1", I color the cells in the column titled "Driver" gold if that driver had the best finishing position (shown in the column titled "Race Finish Position") in their class (represented by the values "Hypercar", "LMP2", and "GT3" in the column "Class"  using this MINIFS formula:

```
=G7=MINIFS(G$7:G$21,C$7:C$21,"Hypercar")
```

I would like to do the same for a column in another sheet pictured here [Sheet "Driver Standings"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38eoX.png)titled "Driver Standings". I looked at options for this and it seems I'll have to use the INDIRECT function. I tried this in the conditional formatting

```
=G7=MINIFS(INDIRECT("Week 1!G$7:G$21,C$7:C$21,"Hypercar""))
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `INDIRECT` twice, once for each range:

```cpp
=G7=MINIFS(INDIRECT("Week 1!G7:G21"),INDIRECT("Week 1!C7:C21"),"Hypercar")
```

Comment: I copied and pasted that into the conditional formatting and it shows as a valid formula but doesn't change the color of the cells. I tried this =MINIFS(INDIRECT("Week 1!G$7:G$21"),INDIRECT("Week 1!C$7:C$21"),"Hypercar") and it colored the whole row. Adding G7 back to the front removes the color again. Any tips?

Comment: I tried this: =INDIRECT("Week 1!G$7")=MINIFS(INDIRECT("Week 1!G$7:G$21"),INDIRECT("Week 1!C$7:C$21"),"Hypercar") and it also colors the whole row.

Comment: please share a sample sheet.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you meant but here is a link to a copy of the spreadsheet. Thank you so much for your help. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i01A3eLwO1BHq8J-2xBdKeYlhEEp42r4_pGEwNV9TVc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I realized I could simplify things by using a MAXIFS function within the same sheet, but I ran into a problem there as well. I feel like that path is much simpler, so i posted another question based on it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77975831/maxifs-in-conditional-formatting-affecting-values-outside-of-set-criteria
thank you for your help. I think I'm going to pursue this option instead.