# MAXIFS in conditional formatting affecting values outside of set criteria?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am using MAXIFS in conditional formatting to color cells that contain the highest value in three different categories.As shown here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNqKo.png)
I am trying to format Column E to color gold the cells containing the highest value corresponding with the classes "Hypercar", "LMP2", and "GT3" shown in Column D.

I used the formulas `=E2=MAXIFS(E$2:E$16,D$2:D$16,"Hypercar")`,`=E2=MAXIFS(E$2:E$16,D$2:D$16,"LMP2")`, and `=E2=MAXIFS(E$2:E$16,D$2:D$16,"GT3")` in conditional formatting, and they colored the right cells, but they also colored other cells in Column E that contained the same number even when they did not correspond to the same class in Column D. In the image above you can see that cells E2, E4, E5, E7, and E8 have been colored gold. Only cells E2, E5, and E7 should be gold as E2 holds the highest value corresponding to the "hypercar" class, E5 holds the highest value corresponding to the "LMP2" class, and E7 holds the highest value corresponding to the "GT3" class. I presume cells E4 and E8 are colored as well because they contain the same value as E5 and E7 respectively. How can I prevent them from being colored? I only want cells colored that contain the highest value for each class. Thank you!

Comment: Please share an editable example sheet. Separately, make sure your examples describe your problem. What is the input? What is the desired output? etc. Consult [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as needed.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i01A3eLwO1BHq8J-2xBdKeYlhEEp42r4_pGEwNV9TVc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you have a tab that shows desirable output? If you strip down the example to minimal necessary, it will be both easier to create desired output for yourself and easier for others to read your example.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure what you mean, but I would like it to look like the tab "Copy of Driver Standings".

Comment: That is exactly what I meant. Before I answer, I'd want to know I would be working on the right problem. And the "Copy of Driver Standings" tab shows that. (That's a common requirement for ppl to answer in general.)

Comment: Thank you and thank everyone who has helped! I think it has been fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Added an `extra condition check` wrt. column_D to your existing formula:*

```js
=(D2="Hypercar")*(E2=MAXIFS(E$2:E$16,D$2:D$16,"Hypercar"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I tried to do that like 2 hours ago, but i used an IF function and it didn't work lol.

Comment: @MatthewNewton: Nested `if` works as well. It could be typo or some other error.

Answer (score 0):

The following works.

```js
=and(E2=max(filter(E$2:E,D$2:D="Hypercar")),D2="Hypercar")
```

Your formula does as well if you use `maxif` to check `E2=...` and add in the rest of the above formula.